# discord.py - Error command with DM member

Tags: python, discord, syntax-error, discord.py, dm

I wanted to make an error command for my code, that gets shown when the dms are turned off or the user wasn't found, here's my code:

```
@client.command()
async def DM(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
        message = message or "DM message to be sent"
        await user.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as:

You can read the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.User.send). It will raise a Forbidden error if you can't send the message.

```py
@client.command()
async def DM(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
        message = message or "DM message to be sent"
        try:
            await user.send(message)
        except: 
            await ctx.send("Failed to send Dm")
```